# Android App Crashes :(

Tags: java, android

I'm new on android, and trying to make a love calculator, Here I have two strings of name and I want to add ASCII values of those character's which are same in both of the strings, but every time I do this my app crashes. Can any 1 please help me. I search it all on internet but no one have the reliable answer . Please Help me through this. Here is my MAIN Activity CODE

```
package com.purepush.lovecalculator;

import android.app.Activity;

import android.os.Bundle;

import android.view.Menu;

import android.view.View;

import android.widget.EditText;

import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {


    TextView t1;
    TextView t2;
    TextView t3;
    EditText fName;
    EditText sName;
    String nameF;
    String nameS;
    int sv;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
         t1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
         t2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
         t3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
         fName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
         sName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void buttonClick(View v)
    {

        int avg = 0, count = 0;
        int f ; 
        f=fName.length()+sName.length();
        for(int i = 0 ; i<f; i++)
        {

            nameF=fName.getText().toString();
            nameS=sName.getText().toString();

            if(nameF.charAt(i)==nameS.charAt(i))
            {
                sv = (int)nameF.charAt(i)+ (int)nameS.charAt(i); 
                avg+=sv;
                count=count+100;
            }


        }
        avg = avg/count;
        t3.setText(avg+"");

        }


}
```

Comment: Please put the stacktrace.

Comment: What's the logcat look like when it crashes? It should give you a fairly detailed look at what happened.

Comment: ok dude, never mind there will be no relaible answers for unreliable codes

Comment: a FATAL EXCEPTION : MAIN

Comment: and an illegalStateException

Comment: is this all stacktrace

Comment: Please post the complete stack trace. And I'm intrigued - what does a 'love calculator' do?

Comment: Look at your for loop.

Comment: Just a note: It will help you and us if you gave your variables descriptive names so instead of EditText e1, give it a name describing what the user is expected to enter e.g. `etFirstName`..

Comment: AndrewFielden
Im trying to add ASCII values of all the same characters of both strings and then divide them by count sorry here count++; only not count=count+100; to get the percentage of your love.! and then I update the value of text i.i t3..!

Comment: `u, j, e1, e2, i, t3, f`.  Your code is almost unreadable, certainly, far harder to read than it should be.  Please don't be lazy, follow good coding standards and give your variables proper names.  This stuff went out in the 1980s.

Answer (score 2):

```
    f=e1.length()+e2.length();
    for(int i = 0 ; i<f; i++)
    {

        u=e1.getText().toString();
        j=e2.getText().toString();

        if(u.charAt(i)==j.charAt(i))
        {
            sv = (int)u.charAt(i)+ (int)j.charAt(i); 
            avg+=sv;
            count=count+100;
        }


    }
```

Of course this will crash. `f` is assigned the sum of the lengths of both strings, and when you iterate `i` from `0` to `f` you attempt to read characters beyond the length of `u` and `j`.

The line - `if(u.charAt(i)==j.charAt(i))` crashes when `i` gets higher than the length of either `u` or `j`.

Comment: do you have any solution for this?
Actually I just started this , and want to learn about this,! On other sites it is very difficult to learn about this , so I came here to seek some help..!

Comment: @user3071935 It depends on what you are trying to do. If you want to compare each character of the first string with each character of the second, you should use a nested loop (the outer running over the length of the first string and the inner over the length of the second string). If you only want to compare the characters in the same position, your look should only iterate up to the minimum of the lengths of both strings.

Answer (score 0):

Your best course of action would be to try and debug the problem for yourself. That way you'll learn how to diagnose these sort of things in future.
First set a breakpoint at the line just before the for loop. Then run the application in debug mode (hit the button with the bug icon next to the run button). 
You app will stop at the breakpoint, you can then step through the code line by line, and examine the values of the variables as the execution of your code progresses.

And I completely agree with the comment about your code style. Make variable names descriptive and avoid one character names.